# Reformatting a list to add " " and ,

Tags: java, list, awtrobot, reformat

I have a list like this but much longer in a text document.

```
123451234
1234123
1234567
12345678
```

I need it to be reformatted to

```
"1123451234", "1234123","1234567","123123123","112345678"
```

I have tried the robot class with java in a loop. I can add the " " and the , but the problem is each line is a different length so I can't simply have it click the left arrow a certain amount of times. What could I do? If you need more info please ask and thanks in advance!

Here's the code for the person that asked.

```
Robot r = new Robot(); 

r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_COMMA);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_COMMA);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE);
```

Comment: I'm really curious to see how you used the robot class to attempt to do this. Can you show us please?

Comment: can you also show how you're reading that data in, and how you tried to deal with it? If you describe what you tried to so far, also show the code you used.

Comment: Why can't you edit the text document directly?

Comment: There's a `Home` key, you know...

Comment: Wow, that's quite a low level approach for doing something like this task.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I posted the code in. The data is in a notepad and I am editing directly in the notepad. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @adarshr I'm still learning. Hence why I'm posting on this site. Don't comment insults, at least give some info on how I can improve. Thanks.

Comment: @SolidCloudinc That was surely not an insult. I really appreciate what you have done there. There was an instance where I had to something similar to automate a flash game!

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this by sending keystrokes to an editor? Can you not use sed or awk?

Comment: @JimGarrison I can, I just didn't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a helper program that will take the data in the text file (for example, `file.txt`) and reformat it like so (untested code, but you get the idea):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("file.txt")));
String line, result = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    result += "\"" + line + "\",";
}
result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1); // remove last comma
// do stuff with result
```

About your Robot-based approach: you can use the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys to jump to the beginning or end of the line:

```
// jump to end
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_END);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_END);

// jump to start
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_HOME;
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_HOME);
```

Comment: OP need to add " as well in the beginning and end of each word.

Comment: I will be trying this.

Comment: @Doorknob BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("file.txt"))); gives an error. Where should I place file.txt?

Comment: @SolidCloudinc What error? Did you remember to `import` the relevant classes?

Comment: @Doorknob Yes, and no suggestions available.

Comment: @Doorknob Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The constructor BufferedReader(FileReader) is undefined
 FileReader cannot be resolved to a type
 File cannot be resolved to a type

 at Format.main(Format.java:8)

Comment: @Doorknob sorry for all the question but now i get Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at Format.main(Format.java:11)

Comment: @SolidCloudinc `The system cannot find the file specified` Please actually read the error messages. The last one was quite clear, and this one is too.

Comment: @Doorknob Right but where do I save the file?

Comment: @SolidCloudinc In the same folder as your program... or just do `new File("C:/some/path/file.txt");`. I have to go now, hope you solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do this programmatically, I'd suggest just opening any decent text editor such as Sublime Text and do a find - replace with regular expressions switched on.

Find `(\d+)\n`

Replace with `"$1",`

With this, if you do a replace all, you'll end up with

```
"123451234","1234123","1234567",12345678
```

So, just do the last one manually.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed command-line

```
$ cat test.dat
123451234
1234123
1234567
12345678

$ sed -e's/^\(.*\)$/"\1"/' test.dat
"123451234"
"1234123"
"1234567"
"12345678"
```

The regular expression matches the entire line and wraps it with quotes.  This outputs to stdout, but just redirect to a file to save the output:

```
$ sed -e's/^\(.*\)$/"\1"/' test.dat > quoted.dat
```